# Semantic UI Search bar - can you cut off the description so it only shows first few words, but still searches all words?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, semantic-ui

New to Semantic UI. My application uses Java, Springboot and Thymeleaf. The search capability is really convenient. The way it is set up in the code makes it so it searches the title, description, and url. This is great, except when you type in a word it shows the whole article content. Is there a way to cut the displayed content down to just first few words?
I've tried regex, splicing and slicing, maxLength... it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```html
<script th:inline="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var content = [
        <th:block th:each="topic : ${topics}">
            <th:block th:each="article : ${topic.articles}" >
                { title: [[${article.title}]], description: [[${article.contentText}]], url: [[${"/article/"+topic.id+"/"+article.id}]], },
            </th:block>
        </th:block>
        ];

        $(function() {
          $('.ui.search').search({
                source: content
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, when using Thymeleaf you can use `#strings.abbreviate` to cut a text. I have used it inside my html, but never in a script, but maybe it can work. Try this out.

```
<th:block th:each="topic : ${topics}">
     <th:block th:each="article : ${topic.articles}" >
            { title: [[${article.title}]], description: [[${#strings.abbreviate(article.contentText, 50)}]], url: [[${"/article/"+topic.id+"/"+article.id}]], },
      </th:block>
</th:block>
```

This should cut your description and leave only the first 50 characters.

Comment: You are welcome Stacie! If you don't mind voting my answer up for some 10 extra points that would be awesome :)

Comment: You're the best! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should included both a trimmed and non-trimmed version within the structure. Either you can do that in the controller that's used to pass the topics/articles, or you can do that as Alain mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53160497), by using `#strings.abbbreviate()`:

```
<th:block th:each="topic : ${topics}">
     <th:block th:each="article : ${topic.articles}" >
            { title: [[${article.title}]], description: [[${article.contentText}]], trimmedDescription: [[${#strings.abbreviate(article.contentText, 20)}]], url: [[${"/article/"+topic.id+"/"+article.id}]], },
      </th:block>
</th:block>
```

Now you have to configure Semantic UI properly by setting `searchFields` to include the non-trimmed descriptions, and `fields` to include the trimmed version, for example:

```js
$('.ui.search').search({
  source: content,
  searchFields: ['description'],
  fields: {description: 'trimmedDescription'}
});
```

In the code example above, I'm assuming that you stored the trimmed descriptions in a field called `trimmedDescription`.

---

Be aware that both your code and my solution are limited in scalability. The Semantic UI search component supports serving results over a separate REST API, and you should do that if you have many results, or if you have very long descriptions.

Comment: Thanks @g00glen00b - I agree, this is now not searching the whole article and just the first 50 characters. Where should I be saving the trimmedDescription as a variable though if I use Alian's answer?

Comment: @Stacie You should both include the original `description` field and a new field called `trimmedDescription` that does exactlh what Alain described. I've clarified that in my answer.